# CKEditor: [CKEditorWebpackPlugin] Error: Too many JS assets has been found during the compilation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ckeditor

I am updating the CKEditor packages in my Rails/React app from ~12 to the latest version 27.  When running the app locally in my `webpack-dev-server` I see this error message below, and I'm not sure how to determine which option is best/correct?

```
[CKEditorWebpackPlugin] Error: Too many JS assets has been found during the compilation. You should use one of the following options to specify the strategy:
 - use `addMainLanguageTranslationsToAllAssets` to add translations for the main language to all assets,
 - use `buildAllTranslationsToSeparateFiles` to add translation files via `<script>` tags in HTML file,
 - use `translationsOutputFile` to append translation to the existing file or create a new asset.For more details visit https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev/tree/master/packages/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin.
```

---

The `environment.js` file currently looks like this:

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker")
const typescript = require("./loaders/typescript")
const GitRevisionPlugin = require("git-revision-webpack-plugin")

environment.loaders.append("typescript", typescript)

environment.plugins.prepend(
  "Define",
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    // On Heroku git is not available, but SOURCE_VERSION is provided
    GIT_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.SOURCE_VERSION || new GitRevisionPlugin().commithash()),
    BUILD_TIME: JSON.stringify(new Date().toISOString()),
  })
)

environment.plugins.prepend(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    jquery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  })
)

environment.config.externals = ["cloudinary"]

// Add support for CKEditor 5.
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin")

environment.plugins.prepend(
  "CKEditor",
  new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
    language: "en",
  })
)

// Define custom loaders for CKEditor's SVG and CSS files.
environment.loaders.append("CKEditorSVGLoader", require("./loaders/ckeditor/svg"))
environment.loaders.append("CKEditorCSSLoader", require("./loaders/ckeditor/css"))

// Tell the standard CSS and file loaders to ignore CKEditor's CSS and SVG files. We have our own loaders for those.
environment.loaders.get("css").exclude = /(\.module\.[a-z]+$)|(ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css)/
environment.loaders.get("file").exclude = /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/

module.exports = environment
```

Project is running:

- ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 6.0.3.6
- webpack-dev-server": 3.11.2

Comment: was your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet, it got put on hold for a bit with some more pressing matters :(

Comment: Please can you keep the thread updated if you get a solution?

Comment: Sure I will try to do that :)

Comment: up on this. anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue too while making a [custom build](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/quick-start.html#building-the-editor-from-source) in CKEditor. So i assume you followed [these instructions](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source.html#webpack-encore) ("Webpack Encore" section).

*In this solution, i am using the **webpack.config.js** config file (**PHP** setup using **Encore**). The config file name may change from one language to another. If you are not using Encore (i recommand using it), the code may vary a bit, but the logic is the same.*

**1. If you don't need translations for your build:**

Simply remove this part from **webpack.config.js**:

```
.addPlugin( new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
    language: 'pl'
} ) )
```

**2. If your need translations:**

Add the `addMainLanguageTranslationsToAllAssets` option and set it on `true`, like this:

```
.addPlugin( new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
    language: 'pl',
    addMainLanguageTranslationsToAllAssets: true
} ) )
```

Comment: - use `addMainLanguageTranslationsToAllAssets` to add translations for the main language to all assets,
- use `buildAllTranslationsToSeparateFiles` to add translation files via `<script>` tags in HTML file,
- use `translationsOutputFile` to append translation to the existing file or create a new asset